# Posting data to webpages while keeping the sessions and cookie in c#

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a easy way to post data to webpages while keeping the cookies. for example you login to somewhere, and later you do some new actions.

What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear.  What exactly are you asking? 'keeping the sessions and cookies' is a bit ambiguous as sessions and cookies are not cleared when POSTing.

Also are you using web forms, or asp mvc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of ways how you can do this:

1. [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx)
2. [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx)
3. [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/)
4. [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx)/ AxWebBrowser

The way you choose depends on your specific requirements. I prefer to use HttpWebRequest because it gives flexibility and speed.